# Play only one song

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, lumia-640, groove

I added a folder with a couple of audio files to my Music folder. When I click on one of those files in file explorer - it plays only that file in Groove. But when I click on it in My Music in Groove - it plays many files.

How do I make it play only one file from within Groove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. Some are:

### A playlist

Add the song to a playlist and play that list.

### Repeat one

Tap repeat until Groove repeats only one song.

### Create a single album

Since you have the music file you can edit its info and create [a single album](https://mediaredirect.microsoft.com/music/Album/730B9A0A-0100-11DB-89CA-0019B92A3933) for that song yourself. Then play that album.

Comment: A playlist does seem like a workaround. I hope, though, that there's a simpler way. +1.

Comment: @ispiro maybe a single album of your own?

Comment: Creating a playlist or album for that file seem to be good workarounds. It seems like there's no non-workaround way. So accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the `repeat` icon to your desired preference. If you want it to repeat a playlist or all songs, touch it once and it should highlight that its active.

If you would like to repeat one track, click on it again, and it should show you a tiny `1` superscript on the icon, to signify that the player will be repeating/looping one track:

[image]